# Getting n'th order coefficient from series expansion in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, taylor-series

I have a polynomial defined using numpy's poly1d:

```
import numpy as np

p = np.poly1d([-1.37970733e+07,  8.02055768e+07, -1.98442743e+08,  2.70981281e+08,
       -2.20611918e+08,  1.07019785e+08, -2.85873914e+07,  3.24251782e+06])
```

I then do a series expansion of this polynomial about a point I call `radMax = 0.80868373`. Here is how I do the series expansion:

```
from sympy import series, Symbol, Poly
x = Symbol('x')
polyExpand = p(x).series(x,radMax,3)/(p(radMax)/0.0523772)
```

This gives me the expansion I want, and I want the coefficient of the 2nd order term. If you run the above code, you will see that this coefficient is "0.2843162879664". I would like to extract this coefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to address the coefficients by terms:

```py
from sympy import sympify
print(polyExpand.as_coefficients_dict()[sympify(f"(x - {radMax}) ** 2")])
```

If you would like to get the coefficients by indices:

```py
coeffs = list(polyExpand.as_coefficients_dict().values())
print(coeffs[2]) # order n = 2
```

These will correctly output `-0.284316287966400`. You forgot about the minus.

Comment: Is it possible to get the coefficients as a list or array instead of as a dict? Ideally in some ordered way. While your method is working for me with just the code I gave above, I'm generating several different polynomials p and I seem to be running into an issue where the precision of radMax is different from the precision used in the expansion. Specifically for eg, I get `radMax = 0.8086880013254281`, whereas in the dictionary the key is `(x - 0.808688001325428)**2`. Notice that the former has one extra digit.

Comment: @Zach Added it into the answer.